Is GLFWTerminate Leaking Memory?
I have been using GLFW in a recent project of mine, and felt it was necessary to run the code through Valgrind for a leak check. However, when I did, two memory leaks were reported during the close of my program! I'm certain that I'm not missing anything cleanup-wise, so I'm writing this question as a sanity check. Can anyone find anything wrong with my program that would make it leak memory? Both the Valgrind output and source code is below.
==113534== HEAP SUMMARY:
==113534==     in use at exit: 183,908 bytes in 2,272 blocks
==113534==   total heap usage: 30,407 allocs, 28,135 frees, 14,042,095 bytes allocated
==113534== 
==113534== 184 (40 direct, 144 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 2,203 of 2,225
==113534==    at 0x484BC13: calloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:1675)
==113534==    by 0x5F4B44F: ???
==113534==    by 0x5F407A0: ???
==113534==    by 0x138754: _glfwInitEGL (in /mnt/Storage/Development/Current/leto/build/Leto/Leto)
==113534==    by 0x133B26: _glfwCreateWindowWayland (in /mnt/Storage/Development/Current/leto/build/Leto/Leto)
==113534==    by 0x1239E2: glfwCreateWindow (in /mnt/Storage/Development/Current/leto/build/Leto/Leto)
==113534==    by 0x1149B1: CreateWindow (Window.c:28)
==113534==    by 0x114131: main (Main.c:5)
==113534== 
==113534== 2,872 (2,688 direct, 184 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 2,221 of 2,225
==113534==    at 0x484BC13: calloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:1675)
==113534==    by 0x5F4B9AF: ???
==113534==    by 0x5F4C0CF: ???
==113534==    by 0x5E738F4: ???
==113534==    by 0x138671: _glfwInitEGL (in /mnt/Storage/Development/Current/leto/build/Leto/Leto)
==113534==    by 0x133B26: _glfwCreateWindowWayland (in /mnt/Storage/Development/Current/leto/build/Leto/Leto)
==113534==    by 0x1239E2: glfwCreateWindow (in /mnt/Storage/Development/Current/leto/build/Leto/Leto)
==113534==    by 0x1149B1: CreateWindow (Window.c:28)
==113534==    by 0x114131: main (Main.c:5)
==113534== 
==113534== LEAK SUMMARY:
==113534==    definitely lost: 2,728 bytes in 2 blocks
==113534==    indirectly lost: 328 bytes in 3 blocks
==113534==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==113534==    still reachable: 180,852 bytes in 2,267 blocks
==113534==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks

// Window.h
#include <Diagnostic/Platform.h>
#include <glad.h>
#include <glfw3.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef struct
{
    char title[128];
    GLFWwindow* _w;
} window_t;

const window_t* CreateWindow(const char* title);
void DestroyWindow(void);

// Window.c
#include "Window.h"
#include "Output/Reporter.h"
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

static window_t application_window = {"", NULL};

const window_t* CreateWindow(const char* title)
{
    if (application_window._w != NULL)
    {
        ReportWarning(double_window_creation);
        return &application_window;
    }

    bool init_success = glfwInit();
    if (!init_success) ReportError(glfw_init_failed);

    // OpenGL Core v4.6
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 4);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 6);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

    strncat(application_window.title, title, 64);
    strncat(application_window.title, " | v" __LETO__VERSION__STRING__,
            64);

    application_window._w =
        glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, application_window.title, NULL, NULL);
    if (application_window._w == NULL)
        ReportError(glfw_window_create_failed);

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(application_window._w);
    if (!gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc)glfwGetProcAddress))
        ReportError(opengl_init_failed);

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(application_window._w))
    {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        glfwSwapBuffers(application_window._w);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    return &application_window;
}

void DestroyWindow(void)
{
    if (application_window._w == NULL)
    {
        ReportWarning(preemptive_window_free);
        return;
    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(NULL);
    glfwDestroyWindow(application_window._w);
    glfwTerminate();
}

// Main.c
#include <Windowing/Window.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    CreateWindow("Leto");
    DestroyWindow();
}


Yes it is leaking. You need a debug build of glfw (or a debuginfo package) to get more information. Also does this help https://trycatchdebug.net/news/1380049/glfw-memory-leaks-with-valgrind?

@PaulFloyd Within the source you provided, they create a monitor object and destroy it to prevent self-imposed leakage. Mine seems to be a problem with EGL, or at least my use of it. My problem is that I can't directly interface with EGL through GLFW, unfortunately, and even with a debug build of GLFW the ??? functions in the Valgrind output still separate me from figuring out what the real issue is. Any ideas?

If you can get the line numbers for e.g. glfwInitEGL you should see what is being called.

@PaulFloyd Good idea, I managed to figure out ln. 503, which is a call to an internal GLFW function to create an EGL context. Beyond that, I have zero idea, as getting Valgrind to report line numbers and function names past that point seems to be impossible.
